# Instance variables behaviour in multithreading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I am trying to run a program with 4 threads. I would like to know about the behaviour of instance variables in threading. In this I need to pass a value to the method. So, I am doing like this to pass the value and use it for further processing.

```
@Component
class ThreadExample implements Runnable
{
    String file;

    public void setFile(String file)
    {
       this.file = file;
    }
    @override
    public void run()
    {
       readFile(file);
    }
    public void readFile(String fileName)
    {  
        //logic for reading file
    }
}

@component
class ThreadCall
{
    @Autowired
    ThreadExample ex;

     public void testThread()
     {
        ExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        getFiles()
          .stream()
          .forEach(f-> {
               ex.setFile(f);
               executor2.submit(ex);                             
           });
     }

}
```

`getFiles()` api returns list of file names. I am trying to do it in `Spring`.
Here, 4 threads will work simultaneously.  Object `ex` is `autowired` so it will be instantiated only once.

How `file` variable value would effect?

I am thinking like,  one thread will try to set file through `setFile(file)` and it will be changed by another threads before using it in `readFile`.

How to overcome this issue? How to pass a value in multithreading?
Will my problem be solved if I make 'file' as `volatile` ?

Comment: "Object ex is autowired so it will be instantiated only once." Eh, not really. More accurately, `ThreadExample` is a component, so it will only be instantiated once.

Comment: There appears to be a logical mismatch between what you want to do, and how you want to do that. When you have a threadpool, you typically want to have several new threads submitted, not a singleton submitted over and over again

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
@Component
class ThreadExample implements Runnable
{
    String file;

    public void setFile(String file)
```

And

> Object ex is autowired so it will be instantiated only once.

That can't work. You have:

```
executor2.submit(ex);
```

You pass the **same** object to multiple tasks that are supposed to do something specific with in parallel. Worse, you push different values into that single object, and somehow magically expect that each task sees exactly that value that you intended for it to see. What will happen: these things happen on different threads, so the outcome is (probably) totally random, aka indeterministic.

Long story short: when you have multiple "things" that need to be done, over time, then you can't use a "singleton-like" container to dispatch your parameters. `volatile` will not help with that, not at all.

The answer is: in order to make this work, `ThreadExample` can't be a "singleton", so that @Component annotation that turns it into a singleton must go away. If doing so "collides" with your other design ideas, then you have to step back and rework your design.

Comment: Re, '...multiple "threads"...' Instead of using the scare quotes, you could call  them what they are---multiple _tasks_ that potentially could be executed by different threads.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks, good point. Adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: @GhostCat One doubt, every variable except `file` is local to `readFile()` method. So, I am thinking all metod local variables are instantiated for every call even though object `ex` is singleton. Only problem is `file`. Correct me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make ThreadExample as prototype bean.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class ThreadExample implements Runnable
{
    String file;

    public void setFile(String file)
    {
       this.file = file;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       readFile(file);
    }
    public void readFile(String fileName)
    {  
        //logic for reading file
    }
}
```

Then instead of injecting ThreadExample bean in the ThreadCall you have to inject application context:

```
@Component
class ThreadCall
{
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;


     public void testThread()
     {
        ExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        getFiles()
          .stream()
          .forEach(f-> {
            ThreadExample ex= context.getBean(ThreadExample.class);   
               ex.setFile(f);
               executor2.submit(ex);                             
           });
     }

}
```

When you call this code , basically each ThreadExample will be a new bean.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What happend If I `Autowired` another object in `ThreadExample` which is singleton and it should be singleton. Will it behave like `prototype` ?

Comment: Yes , As long as u have declared ThreadExample as prototype and you are using application context to get its instance, spring will give you fresh object for ThreadExample. Also during creation of this new object it will check its dependency and if you have autowired a singleton bean , then it will inject that singleton bean into the prototype bean (In this case which is ThreadExample).

In my last project we had validators which were prototype & i injected single ton repositories inside.Every time i asked new instance of validators from application context, spring was injecting repos as well